# How to find a provider of a package in Yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, yocto-recipe

In Yocto, is there any bitbake/oe-pkgdata-util command which can give the info about which recipe is the provider of a particular package? in other words, how can I find the PROVIDER of a particular package?

Comment: You can look on recipe path or use: http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/kirkstone/recipes/ for search and find packet you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bitbake-layers` to retrieve the recipes providing a given package.

```
bitbake-layers show-recipes <package-name>
```

This will a list of matching recipes and the provided versions for each entry.
Additional information about similar alternatives can be found at the [NXP website](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors-Knowledge-Base/Useful-bitbake-commands/ta-p/1128559)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bitbake` command with some filtering.

For example, if I know that my `linux-example` provides the `virtual/kernel` package:

```bash
bitbake -e | awk -F '[_=]' '/PREFERRED_PROVIDER.*linux-example/ { print $3 }'
```

Result:

```bash
virtual/kernel
```

Or:

```bash
bitbake -e linux-example | grep ^PROVIDES
```

Result:

```bash
PROVIDES="linux-example  virtual/kernel"
```

So, you can check if the first command returns something then that is the provider, or the second command contains a name other than the recipe name itself.

Comment: In your example, I am interested on 'PROVIDES="linux-example  virtual/kernel" ' is from which .bb or .bbclass file. I want to know the name of the recipe provides a package.

Comment: `linux-example` is the recipe name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `oe-pkgdata-util lookup-recipe <package-name>`.

For example

```
oe-pkgdata-util lookup-recipe libssl
```

outputs

```
openssl
```